# Eclipse CDT: Set select a option in Tool settings tab from Properties dialog?

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

I can set select "Settings" node in *Properties* dialog of the project.

But I would like to set select "Miscellaneous" option in Tool Settings tab as picture below.

[image]

How can I programatically open the property page and have "Miscellaneous" selected in the "Tool Settings" tab?

Comment: Do you mean programatically open dialog and select?

Comment: Yes bro. How can I do it? Could you please help me?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible with what is there today. The paths for opening properties/preferences pages only apply to the left hand side. I would be happy to review a patch to CDT that added this functionality. https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing

Comment: PS I have expanded "it" to be what it meant, perhaps that will trigger someone else reading the question to have more insights.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have misunderstood the question and deleted my answer. So you want to implement a command that opens the project _Properties_ dialog and in _C/C++ Build > Settings_ selects the _GCC C Compiler > Miscellaneous_ node, right? For the programmatically select [Eclipse SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) or [Eclipse RCPTT](http://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jonah Graham and howlger!
Thank you so much for your comment.
I would like to show my way to open Properties dialog and auto select "Settings" page like this:
PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(Display.getDefault()
.getActiveShell(), selectedProject, PAGE_ID, null,
null);

Comment: PAGE_ID is a String (id of Settings page): "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.properties.Page_BuildSettings" Although I know ID of "Miscellaneous" but I don't know how to set this ID for which component to select "Miscellaneous" (It will be selected when dialog opening)?

Comment: @DuongNguyen as mentioned, the createPropertyDialogOn() only supports selecting stuff on the left hand, the rest of the parameters are passed to the CDT page being opened. As the receiver (the page) needs to interpret that part, a patch is welcome for the settings page to support that. https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing

Comment: PS You need to override org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.applyData(Object) in org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.properties.Page_BuildSettings and then use that object to continue your selection to Miscellaneous. (through the hierarchies of ui elements)

Comment: @JonahGraham which component I can put in applyData method?
Could you please give me a example?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @DuongNguyen can't give you an example, but you override applyData in org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.properties.Page_BuildSetti‌​ngs -- look for other classes that have overridden applyData in the workspace for ideas

Comment: I will try
Thank you so much!